# Kendo AutoComplete set custom CSS class instead of the default?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Kendo Autocomplete input has default class named k-input.

I would like to ask, how can I set complete custom class (width, height, etc) for these input?

I tried to find some informations in documentation but without luck:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#fields-options

Could somebody tell me how can I do it please?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#yourElementsId").removeClass("k-input");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `id` of your autocomplete is `countries` do:

```
var ac = $("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({
    ...
}).data("kendoAutoComplete");
// Setting width
ac.wrapper.css("width", "300px");
// Setting height
ac.input.css("height", "3em");
```

Or using CSS for setting height:

```
#countries {
    height: 3em;
}
```

**NOTE** You can also set the height using only CSS but you cannot set the width only to one autocomplete. The CSS would be:

```
span.k-widget.k-autocomplete.k-header {
    width: 500px;
}
```